# GCP / exporting disk image to Storage bucket fails

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, service, export, account

I'm trying to export a disk image I've build in GCP and export it as a vmdk to a storage bucket.

The export through an error message complaining about service account not found. I can't remember having deleted such a user account. For me it should exist since the creation of the project.

How can I re-create a default service account without taking the risk to loose all my compute engine resources? Which roles should I give to this service account?

```
[image-export-ext.export-disk.setup-disks]: 2021-10-06T18:52:00Z CreateDisks: Creating disk "disk-export-disk-os-image-export-ext-export-disk-j8vpl".
[image-export-ext.export-disk.setup-disks]: 2021-10-06T18:52:00Z CreateDisks: Creating disk "disk-export-disk-buffer-j8vpl".
[image-export-ext.export-disk]: 2021-10-06T18:52:01Z Step "setup-disks" (CreateDisks) successfully finished.
[image-export-ext.export-disk]: 2021-10-06T18:52:01Z Running step "run-export-disk" (CreateInstances)
[image-export-ext.export-disk.run-export-disk]: 2021-10-06T18:52:01Z CreateInstances: Creating instance "inst-export-disk-image-export-ext-export-disk-j8vpl".
[image-export-ext]: 2021-10-06T18:52:07Z Error running workflow: step "export-disk" run error: step "run-export-disk" run error: operation failed &{ClientOperationId: CreationTimestamp: Description: EndTime:2021-10-06T11:52:07.153-07:00 Error:0xc000712230 HttpErrorMessage:BAD REQUEST HttpErrorStatusCode:400 Id:5314937137696624317 InsertTime:2021-10-06T11:52:02.707-07:00 Kind:compute#operation Name:operation-1633546321707-5cdb3a43ac385-839c7747-2ca655ee OperationGroupId: OperationType:insert Progress:100 Region: SelfLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/savvy-bonito-207708/zones/us-east1-b/operations/operation-1633546321707-5cdb3a43ac385-839c7747-2ca655ee StartTime:2021-10-06T11:52:02.708-07:00 Status:DONE StatusMessage: TargetId:840687976797195965 TargetLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/savvy-bonito-207708/zones/us-east1-b/instances/inst-export-disk-image-export-ext-export-disk-j8vpl User:494995903825@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com Warnings:[] Zone:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/savvy-bonito-207708/zones/us-east1-b ServerResponse:{HTTPStatusCode:200 Header:map[Cache-Control:[private] Content-Type:[application/json; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Wed, 06 Oct 2021 18:52:07 GMT] Server:[ESF] Vary:[Origin X-Origin Referer] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[0]]} ForceSendFields:[] NullFields:[]}:
Code: EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
Message: The resource '494995903825-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found.
[image-export-ext]: 2021-10-06T18:52:07Z Workflow "image-export-ext" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).
[image-export-ext]: 2021-10-06T18:52:08Z Workflow "image-export-ext" finished cleanup.
[image-export] 2021/10/06 18:52:08 step "export-disk" run error: step "run-export-disk" run error: operation failed &{ClientOperationId: CreationTimestamp: Description: EndTime:2021-10-06T11:52:07.153-07:00 Error:0xc000712230 HttpErrorMessage:BAD REQUEST HttpErrorStatusCode:400 Id:5314937137696624317 InsertTime:2021-10-06T11:52:02.707-07:00 Kind:compute#operation Name:operation-1633546321707-5cdb3a43ac385-839c7747-2ca655ee OperationGroupId: OperationType:insert Progress:100 Region: SelfLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/savvy-bonito-207708/zones/us-east1-b/operations/operation-1633546321707-5cdb3a43ac385-839c7747-2ca655ee StartTime:2021-10-06T11:52:02.708-07:00 Status:DONE StatusMessage: TargetId:840687976797195965 TargetLink:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/savvy-bonito-207708/zones/us-east1-b/instances/inst-export-disk-image-export-ext-export-disk-j8vpl **User:494995903825@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com** Warnings:[] Zone:https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/savvy-bonito-207708/zones/us-east1-b ServerResponse:{HTTPStatusCode:200 Header:map[Cache-Control:[private] Content-Type:[application/json; charset=UTF-8] Date:[Wed, 06 Oct 2021 18:52:07 GMT] Server:[ESF] Vary:[Origin X-Origin Referer] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[0]]} ForceSendFields:[] NullFields:[]}: Code: EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND; Message: The resource **'494995903825-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found.**
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_export:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to IAM & Admin > IAM and check whether your default SA is there.

If deleted you can recover within 30 days.

[How to check if it is deleted?](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#finding-numeric-id)

[To recover](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#iam-service-accounts-undelete-gcloud). One cannot recover a default compute service account after 30 days.

If all the above fails, then you might need to go the [custom SA route](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#custom-service-account), or [share an image with a project that has a default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images#share-images-within-organization).